# Genius keyboard and mouse issues

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, keyboard-layout

I have an old keyboard (2005/2006) Genius multimedia KB-21e Scroll and a mouse of the same brand NetScroll 120, of both I put pictures below.

[image: Teclado Genius KB-21e]
[image: detalle]
[image: detalle2]

[image: Mouse NetScroll 120]

My difficulty is the following, from the keyboard, the keys do not work: Stop, Refresh, Search, My Computer, Excel and Word, it is also curious that it does not turn on or activate the Scroll Lock; it is the case of the mouse, the scroll wheel button does not react, it works because it clicks but its function is not activated. How can I solve these problems?

Comment: Read `man xev`, and use `xev` to see what your keyboard produces whan you type a key. `man showkey` shows another way to see what keys say. Read `man 5 keymaps` to see about keyboard mapping.

Comment: @waltinator What should I do? I saw what it says What should I do? I saw what it says

Comment: @waltinator I already could solve it. Uninstall the Spanish and reinstalled it on the advice of another person on a page, so I let myself add new keyboard shortcuts, told me that it must have been an error in the installation of the keyboard language. In case the Excel and Word keys do not work, do not register them `xev` or `man 5 keymaps`.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard shoud've come with driver CD. Install the driver. This keyboard was the best keyboard I ever had. Sad they're not making them anymore. if u don't have the cd, then just type the model of it in google and add "driver download" - should give u a link.